# using null-coalesing operator in else if condition

Tags: c#

Is it possible to simplify the below condition using the null-coalescing operator or any other simplified code?

```
int? c,a,b;
if(a!=null)
{
  c = a;
}
else if(b!=null)
{
  c = b;
}
else
{
  c = null;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Normally `c = a ?? b` would do it. But `int` isn't nullable so I'm not sure what is going on in your example.

Comment: I was just going to say what John did.

Comment: `int c = a ?? b ?? default(int);` is probably what you're looking for, assuming you're okay with `0` instead of `null`, or just `int? c = a ?? b;` if you want `c` to be nullable.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention c is a nullable integer. I have updated now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = a ?? b ?? null;
```

Although if your catch is null anyways then you only really need

```
c = a ?? b;
```

Edit: As other users have stated it's important that your int is nullable (int?) if you're working with them.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like:

```
int? c = a ?? (b ?? null)
```

Note that according to your if-else statement, `c` has to be `int?` type. For the same reason, it makes sense both `a` and `b` are of `int?` type.

Hence, as `b` may be `null`, the same expression can be rewritten as:

```
int? c = a ?? b;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that they are all of Type `int?`

```
int? c = a ?? b; //no need for an explicit null. If b is null so will c be.
```

because the question doesn't make sense if they are of Type `int`.